# Как сделать триггер на неправильное значение textbox, и чтобы кнопка стала неактивной? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть приложение с textbox (вводится цена от 0 до 100 тысяч), значение которого привязано к значению slider. Если значение текстбокса не содержится у слайдера (ошибка привязки) - текстбокс становится красным. Но как сделать так, чтобы, например,одна кнопка при таком раскладе стала неактивной? Советовать регулярные выражения не нужно

Comment: Не хватает контекста. Можно ведь использовать готовый IntegerUpDown, который не даст ввести значение вне диапазона. Если MVVM, то при неправильном значении просто пусть CanExecute команды кнопки дает false. А если ValidationRule (если кто-то этим пользуется), то там вроде бы создается маршрутизируемое событие, которое можно поймать и выключить кнопку.

Comment: Для этого достаточно зайти в [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-binding-validation) и увидеть там `<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">`